# Class 'App\Model' not found after add Bican\Roles

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using the library Bican Roles. I change User.php for:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Bican\Roles\Traits\HasRoleAndPermission;
use Bican\Roles\Contracts\HasRoleAndPermission as HasRoleAndPermissionContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract, HasRoleAndPermissionContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, HasRoleAndPermission,Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'surnames', 'email', 'password','phone',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

When try to register a new userthrow the following error:

> Class 'App \ Model' not found

I have tried to add it

> use User;

etc but still not working, any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

to the top of your class declaration, not `use User;`

The error you're getting is

> Class 'App \ Model' not found

not

> Class 'User' not found

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```